# Automating computing docker images on AWS E2C machines

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ansible, capistrano

I would like to distribute some of my computing programs on multiple machines when a specific process is started from a web gui.
For this, I need to start several aws e2c machines, deploy my software (docker), run the programs, and shut down the e2c instances again.
During all times I would like to have an api to query the status of the cluster (visualizing it in my own web gui in ruby on rails).

Now I have seen several systems out there like capistrano, ansible, chef,puppet... But since I am new to this topic its very difficult for me to choose one for my task.
I would like to keep the management simple without to dive too deep into the infrastructure science.

Could someone recommend me a specific system which is best suited for the described task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/).

- Agentless (doesn't require you to install software on machines before you can manage then)
- Simple to pick up [the tasks are pretty much YAML and plain English](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html)
- Ansible already has great [EC2](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html) and [Docker](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) modules

Comment: thank you! do you also know of an example/tutorial how to use Ansible with ruby? Will I have to start a shell command or is there an API?